# Symbols count in string masm32

Tags: string, assembly, count, symbols, masm32

I'd like to write a program that counts the amount of specific symbols in string using scasb and masm32, I found the example, but I couldn't figure out why i'm getting errors.
Here's the part of code:

```
.data
str  db '. . .'

len_str=$-str

.code                     

start:                      

  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax
  mov  es,ax
  lea  di,str
  mov  cx, len_str  
  mov  al,' '
  mov  bx,0 
  cld

cycl:
repe scasb
  jcxz exit 
  inc  bx
  jmp  cycl

exit:
```

getting

A2008 syntax error db, str

A2006 syntax error len_str

A2148 invalid symbol type in expression: exit

A2004: symbol type conflict

Comment: Strings are most likely represented in "double quotes"

Answer (score 2):

`str` is an instruction, it is the mnemonic for `Store Task Register`.  You cannot use it as a label name as you are trying to do.  Name it something else and that should take care of your errors